# Is there anything I can do if I found someone copying my content and spreading on FB/Twitter?

Tags: facebook, copyright, twitter, infringement

I made a website and it somehow became very popular last year.

Then later today I found someone just stole my content and spread it in Twitter and Facebook. And many users are sharing that fake website.

I am very upset but I don't know what to do. I reported to Google but even if Google removes it, it's still spreading on Facebook & Twitter.

Is it possible to contact Twitter & Facebook to stop this?

Thanks!

Comment: Put some Google Ads on it and start making money ;)

Comment: @CedricSimon I have ads on it and the other website also have ads on it. I lost money and social media followers and I can't do anything :(

Answer (score 1):

Before you spend a bunch of money in attorneys. Consider your ownership to those articles, or ads. If you can't prove ownership to them by copyrighting them, they are officially public information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the U.S., hire an attorney. They will send a cease and desist letter immediately. Give them 10 days to remove the content, then file a federal law suit. A federal law suit is an extremely serious problem if you are the defendant and likely they will want to settle. You can collect damages and do not have to prove damages directly if they are advertising or profiting at all. Otherwise, you will have to prove damages to demand remanding a cash award. One option is punitive awards. These are often given in egregious situations and it sounds like that case can be made. Punitive awards cannot be demanded, but requested in court.